# How i save the opened levels in my android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, sharedpreferences, adapter

I have a quiz game that i coded by java (using android studio).
My question is how i save the levels that the user opened , when the user closes the app, nothing is saved and the user has to start playing the game from level 1 again , i tried to use SharedPreferences but it doesn't work,cause i have many categories in my app and each one has many levels ,so even when SharedPreferences  work it will not help cause it will save the level of all the categories what the user doesn't open it

edit:sorry I forget to say I using realtime database (firebase) in my app&is there are way exepet room database

```
public class SetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GridView gridView;
private AppCompatDialog loadingDialoge;
private sets_adapter adapter;
private AdView mAdView;
private  int l,sets,level;
private String title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sets);

    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.sets_toolbar);
    gridView=findViewById(R.id.sets_gv);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    l=getIntent().getIntExtra("lvl",0);
    title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    sets=getIntent().getIntExtra("sets",0);

    loadlvl();

    adapter=new sets_adapter(sets,title,level);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);



}

//on back item click
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
        finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





@Override
protected void onPause() {
    savelevel();
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

private void savelevel(){
    SharedPreferences savechange = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savechange.edit();
    editor.putInt("lvl",l);
    editor.commit();
}

private void loadlvl(){
    SharedPreferences savechange = this.getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    level=savechange.getInt("lvl",-1);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can save data to your local database using Room. It is easy to use.

Check documentations here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: I use realtime database(firebase)

Comment: Firebase realtime database is noSQL cloud database and Room provides an abstraction layer over SQLite as local database, they are not the same. Firebase can be very expensive if you are always fetching data from database. So if you have some data that doesn't change, save it to your local database and use it whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Apollo answer. Worked with a similar task, so I decided to supplement answer.

Create Level class:

```
@Entity
public class Level {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "number")
    public int number;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "level_name")
    public String levelName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_open")
    public boolean isOpen;

    public Level(int id, int number, String levelName, boolean isOpen) {
        this.id = id;
        this.levelName = levelName;
        this.isOpen = isOpen;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Dao class:

```
@Dao
public interface LevelDao {
    @Insert
    void insertAll(Level... levels);

    @Query("UPDATE level SET is_open = :isOpen WHERE level_name = :levelName")
    void updateLevel(String levelName, boolean isOpen);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM level WHERE number LIKE :numberLevel")
    Level findByNumber(int numberLevel);
    ...
}
```

LevelDatabase class:

```
@Database(entities = {Level.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class LevelDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract LevelDao levelDao();
}
```

When you have first start of application, open only the first level:

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
    dbLevels = Room.databaseBuilder(this.getApplicationContext(), LevelDatabase.class, 
        "levels-database").addCallback(dbCallback).build();
    LevelDao dao = dbLevels.levelDao();
});
...
// only called once
RoomDatabase.Callback dbCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(() -> {
            Level level1 = new Level(0, 1, "level1", true);
            Level level2 = new Level(1, 2, "level2", false);
            dbLevels.levelDao().insertAll(level1, level2);
        });
    }
};
```

To open a level during the game:

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
    LevelDatabase dbLevels = Room.databaseBuilder(gameActivity.getApplicationContext(),
        LevelDatabase.class, "levels-database").build();
    LevelDao dao = dbLevels.levelDao();
    dao.updateLevel("level2", true);
});
```

Check if open:

```
dao.findByNumber(2).isOpen;
```

Comment: I don't work with room database before ,so it's hard to me to understand this code but thank u a lot and I'll learn it